# Abstractspoon's todolist time tracking report

Tags: windows, to-do

I use Abstractspoon's ToDoList application.

Does anybody know how can I extract time tracking report?

The question as simple as it is: I only need to know how much time I spent for a task and which tasks I was working on.

Comment: To import .csv file into Microsoft Excel 2007, click on Data, then click the From Text button in the Get External Data menu. This will bring up the Text Import Wizard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple as a question: there is a log .csv file which has dateFrom/dateTo and task id.

I leave the question online, just not to forget this ;)

Comment: You can check your own answer as an accepted solution. :) (You don't earn reputation, but make easier for others coming to your question)

Comment: You are right, but it can only happen in 2 days :)